# Datadog alert when Amazon RDS is created

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, datadog

I have an alert in Datadog when CPU Credits are low. The problem is when I create a new RDS in Amazon, initially it has 0 CPU credits and I receive this alert.

How can I avoid this case? I tried to find "time since creation" metric, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [composite monitors](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/monitor_types/composite/#pagetitle)? You should be able to combine your low CPU Credit monitor with another monitor that looks at events from RDS.

Two monitors such as:

- A: CPU Credit < 10
- B: Number of event received about RDS creation > 1 in past hour

A composite monitor: A && !B

(I hope my example makes sense)

Comment: Sounds good, but how can I create the B monitor? Is there a metric called "Number of events"?

Comment: If everything is configured correctly, you should see some RDS events in the [event page](https://app.datadoghq.com/event/stream?query=sources%3Ards). Then you can create [a monitor on this events](https://app.datadoghq.com/monitors#create/event).

In addition, I noticed that in the section "Set alert condition" in your monitor, you should see a parameter named: `Delay evaluation by`. You could set a delay so that you don't get notified in the first 5min for instance (300 sec).

Comment: I got it! But still, even though I group it by "database id" in the event multi-alert monitor, in the composite monitor it shows "Multi-Alert by *". Which means it doesn't do any aggregation and it cannot "join" two monitors. It's strange.

Comment: Can you show the query you are using in the event monitor? You should use something similar to this https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAu4BL9v Then I managed to see `Multi-Alert by dbinstanceidentifier` in my composite monitor.

Comment: Heston, we have a problem. When a database was created a long time ago and you run out of the CPU credits the composite monitor doesn't trigger, because the B trigger haven't received any events and it treats it as "NO DATA", but it should return 0 instead. :(

Comment: I have put this question in the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873617/datadog-event-trigger-returns-no-data-instead-of-0