# Datadog event trigger returns no data instead of 0

Tags: events, datadog

I have created a event monitor( for example

`events('sources:rds event_source:db-instance').by('dbinstanceidentifier').rollup('count').last('1d') >= 1`)

but it returns "NO DATA" when there are no any events.

How to make it return 0 when there are no any events?

Comment: Have you let the monitor run for longer than your evaluation period (1d)?

Comment: Yep, I created it a week ago and I see "N/A" values for 0 count events

Comment: Worked on an example on my side, initially the monitor does not have any data for each `dbinstanceidentifier`. Once, I receive the first event, the count increases and then after the period ends goes down to 0 for the rest of the time. Do you have some screenshots to help the case?

Comment: I got it now. But this behaviour of datadog makes the approach provided in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502004/datadog-alert-when-amazon-rds-is-created useless :(

Comment: Is there any way to manually create an event for the rest of the instances? I just need to make them green

Answer (score 2):

Now you can wrap your monitor's query with `default_zero()` to make it return 0 instead of NO DATA.